# Perform operation in NumPy array except for some values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a simple way to lock/freeze an element within a Numpy Array. I would like to do several operations over a Numpy Array in python while keeping some specific values as they are originally.

for example,

if a have a Numpy Array a ;

```
[[ 1  3  4  5],
  [6  7  8  0],
  [9 10  11 2]]
```

and another Numpy Array b ;

```
[[2  0  4  10],
 [11 5  12  3],
 [6  8  7   9]]
```

and c = a+b but keeping the original values of 3, 8 and 2 in a.

My arrays are quite big and I would like a solution where I don't have to use a for loop, an if statement or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to build a mask, and then [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to populate from either `a` or `a+b` depending on on the result:

```
m = np.isin(a, [3,8,2])
c = np.where(m, a, a+b)
```

Or as @hpaulj suggests, you could also use `where` and `out` in [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html), which would modify `a` in-place:

```
np.add(a, b, where=~np.isin(a,[3,8,2]), out=a)

array([[ 3,  3,  8, 15],
       [17, 12,  8,  3],
       [15, 18, 18,  2]])
```

Comment: You could also use the `where` (and `out`) of `np.add`.

Comment: Right nice suggestion @hpaulj :) Added it to the answer